# How to make quick access to log file of a project?

Tags: phpstorm

If there is a way in PhpStorm 2021.1 to open some files from my project ?
I want quick access to /storage/logs/laravel.log file...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Use Bookmarks. In particular: **Bookmark with mnemonic**. It works on lines as well as whole files.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/bookmarks.html#add-mnemonic-line-bookmark

1. Select a file in the Project View panel
2. Hit the `Edit | Bookmarks | Add Mnemonic Bookmark` shortcut (<kbd>Ctrl+F11</kbd> here on Windows)
3. Select the mnemonic (I suggest selecting numeric `0`..`9` for a fast keyboard navigation since they have default shortcuts already assigned).

   [image]
4. That's it. Now you can press <kbd>Ctrl + digit</kbd> (<kbd>Ctrl + 0</kbd> in this example) to quickly open that file.

   [image]

---

**NOTES:**

1. If you delete the bookmarked file (pretty typical situation for the log files) then the bookmark will be automatically removed (maybe not straight away but on next project opening but still).
2. You can also use `Edit | Bookmarks | Go to Mnemonics...` (<kbd>Ctrl+Shift+F11</kbd> is the default shortcut here on Windows) to navigate between multiple mnemonic bookmarks (if you use Letter mnemonic and do not have custom shortcut for that)
3. You can also use plain/ordinary bookmarks (not mnemonics): the only difference is that you will have to use Bookmarks toolwindow or Bookmarks popup (`Edit | Bookmarks | Show Line Bookmarks...` <kbd>Shift + F11</kbd> here on Windows) to locate and navigate to them.

   [image]
4. Shortcuts can be changed at the usual `Settings/Preferences | Keymap` screen:

   [image]

Comment: Thanks, I found how Mnemonic Bookmark are created, but only within one session. How can I check where bookmarked file  is located and not to clear it after IDE restart?

Comment: @PetroGromovo *"I found how Mnemonic Bookmark are created, but only within one session"* What do you mean by "only within one sessions"? **You need to clarify this with more details.** Because all bookmarks (regardless of their kind) are got remembered between sessions/stored in a config file. As I have mentioned in the answer -- the bookmark can be auto removed if bookmarked file gets deleted (no file = no bookmark)

Comment: @PetroGromovo *"How can I check where bookmarked file is located"* The same -- It's not clear for me what are you asking here. The location is obvious -- it can be seen in the Bookmarks toolwindow. E.g. Looking at my screenshot #2 -- bookmark for the `debug` folder (with `testing` text next to it) . This means that the debug folder is located in the `PROJECT_ROOT/testing/` folder.

Comment: @PetroGromovo **In either case:** Select the bookmark in the Bookmarks toolwindow, then invoke a shortcut for `Navigate | Select In...` -- it can open your OS file manager with that file/folder focused. Or you can invoke the shortcut for `Navigate | File Path` -- this will show a popup menu with all parts of the file path so you can navigate there in your OS file manager.

Comment: @PetroGromovo If you are asking in what config file bookmarks are saved .. then: 1) open `.idea/workspace.xml` in your text editor 2) Locate a line with `<component name="ProjectId"` 3) remember the value of the `id` attribute 4) Open folder where IDE-wide config is stored. For Windows that would normally be `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\JetBrains\PhpStorm2022.1\` and locate `workspace` folder there. 6) Now locate the file named as `id` attribute from step #3 - this is your non-shareable part of your workspace config. Bookmarks are stored here in `<component name="BookmarksManager">` node

Comment: Yes, in my Kubuntu 20 I found file /home/master/.config/JetBrains/PhpStorm2021.1/workspace/25JYhxQkivIWlc4QfNWEEkr9gCd.xml

this file have a lot of config options.
But this file has no BookmarksManager node.


actually this subdirectory has 42 similar files. Looks like any such file is created in any session worked with PhpStorm2021.
I checked content of some of them - none have BookmarksManager node.

Sure, I have never deleted anything inside of this subfolder.
Can I to fix BookmarksManager node issue somehow ?

Comment: @PetroGromovo The path to the config seems correct to me: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#config-directory But please note: if you have installed PhpStorm using JetBrains Toolbox App, the path can be different. Not sure if this will also be different if you are syncing your IDE settings with JetBrains account. So you better double check your `idea.log` to confirm the paths (`PhpStorm | Help | Show Log in XXX`) -- at the start of the IDE session it will log the paths used.

Comment: @PetroGromovo It is possible that you have copy-pasted this whole project (I mean: made a copy and then renamed the folders as if it's a different project; it was done with  `.idea` to avoid configuring the project again). If that's the case then the `ProjectId` can be shared between multiple projects and they overwrite such non-shareable file...

Comment: @PetroGromovo What I suggest here is: 1) make a backup of your current `.idea`; 2) Delete it (while PhpStorm is closed of course). 3) Launch PhpStorm and open that project again -- the IDE will make a new project from those existing files; you will just need to configure it again. This will also give it a new `ProjectId` to avoid such possible issue. See if doing that will make it work.

Comment: @PetroGromovo *"none have BookmarksManager node"*. Odd. I suggest this (in case if the above suggestion will make no much difference). 1) create a file in this project with 100% unique file name (that is unique across whole system -- e.g. use some SHA-2 has or something, 2) Bookmark it. 3) Close the project (or even better the whole IDE) so the config files got saved. 4) Now search for any `.xml` files that contain that filename inside and see the file path and in what node it is found.

Comment: P.S. You may also check the `.idea/workspace.xml` file itself (for Bookmarks nodes) if you have not done it already. Just in case it uses some other mechanics (e.g. bookmarks linked to Tasks & Contexts)

Comment: I tried to remove .idea subdirectory with closed phpstorm as you proposed in 3 projects I work last days.
But looks like bookmarks are lost when I open other project.

Also my phpstorm has option that I can open several phpstorm instances at the same time.
Are there some related options not to lose my bookmarks.

Comment: @PetroGromovo You need to contact PhpStorm Support for this. Use `Help | Contact Support...` to make a support ticket where you can describe your issues and privately attach all requested files. Start with providing your `idea.log` file. Based on your description so far you may need to supply your whole IDE config for them to see what options/setup you have there so they can reproduce it. Without seeing/knowing-in-first-person the setup it is like guessing on the coffee mud.

Comment: I personally do not have such an issues (and never had) and so far have not seen any tickets in PhpStorm's Issue Tracker about loosing/not saving bookmarks. It could be either your specific setup/circumstances ... or even user error of some kind... It is not worth guessing/doing theory crafting. **P.S.** Do you think you can work with 1 project only for a bit to see if the issue will persist in such scenario? Do you think you can make a small screencast/video recording on some dummy test project that would illustrate the issue (it may reveal some ignored details/nuances)